# jQuery - Change text of inner <span name="bar"> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="foo">
...
    <span name="bar">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span name="zzz">dolor sit amet</span>
...
</div>
```

Given that I know the `id` of the `<div>`, how can I change the text of the `<span>` tag with attribute `name=bar`?. Note that there might be several/different `<div>` tags with one `<span name="bar">` each.

I have tried:

```
$("#foo").find("span[@name='bar']").text("Phasellus congue arcu turpis");
```

What is missing/wrong?

Comment: Remove the `@` symbol in the selector

Comment: Note also that the JS console will show you that it's an unrecognized expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span[@name='bar']` is not a valid jQuery selector. You need `span[name='bar']` (remove the `@`).

```
// Notice the simplified/combined selector below
$("#foo span[name='bar']").text("Phasellus congue arcu turpis");
```

If you have several `div`'s that require modification, you should be using a class selector (demonstrated in the fiddle below).

```
// jQuery class selector
$(".divsWithSpans span[name='bar']").text("Phasellus congue arcu turpis");
```

Here's [a quick reference for selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp), and [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd64vk2t/1/) to play with.

---

```js
// ID selector
$("#foo span[name='bar']").text("Phasellus congue arcu turddpis");

 // Class selector
$(".divsWithSpans span[name='bar']").text("Phasellus congue arcu turpis");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!–– ID Selector ––>
<div id="foo">
  <span name="bar"></span>
</div>

<!–– Class selector ––>
<div class="divsWithSpans">
  <span name="bar"></span>
</div>
<div class="divsWithSpans">
  <span name="bar"></span>
</div>
<div class="divsWithSpans">
  <span name="bar"></span>
</div>
<div class="divsWithSpans">
  <span name="bar"></span>
</div>
<div class="divsWithSpans">
  <span name="bar"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, several `div` with that `span[name='bar']`.

- Remove the @ in your selector.

---

```js
$("div").find("span[name='bar']").text("Phasellus congue arcu turpis");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">

    <span name="bar">Lorem Ipsum</span><br>
    <span name="zzz">dolor sit amet</span>

</div>

<div id="nofoo">

    <span name="bar">Lorem Ipsum</span><br>
    <span name="zzz">dolor sit amet</span>

</div>
```

**Hope it helps!**